# dotMemory - finding objects with a short lifespan

Tags: dotmemory

How can I use dotMemory to identify all objects that were created and then collected either as of a snapshot or between two snapshots? It seems like it should be able to but I can't find anywhere that this is discussed (or I don't know the right terms to search with).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a memory traffic view. Note that memory traffic data can't be collected when dotMemory is attached to the already running application due to MS Profiling API restriction.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory/Analyzing_Traffic.html